# OpenGL: setting a texture

Tags: opengl, textures, pyopengl

I'm new to OpenGL and I want it to display the frames that I get from my camera in the background of the window. Therefore I created a quad, converted the frame to a texture and I'm trying to set it as a texture for my quad but I can't seem to find the right way. I tried doing the same like described on [opengl-tutorial.org](http://opengl-tutorial.org) in tutorial 5. I'm using Python => PyOpenGL and the python scripts from https://github.com/Jerdak/opengl_tutorials_python/ worked.
But when I try to combine that with the scripts from https://rdmilligan.wordpress.com/2016/04/15/display-video-using-opengl/ where he converts the camera frame to a texture, I can't make it work.
Here is my code,at the moment it would simply display a coloured cube in front of a coloured quad, but the quad should have a texture on it:

```
glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT)

glUseProgram(program_id)

glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST)
glDepthFunc(GL_LESS)

...
mvp = ProjectionMatrix * ViewMatrix * ModelMatrix

glUniformMatrix4fv(cube_matrix_id, 1, GL_FALSE, mvp.data)

# 1rst attribute buffer : vertices
glEnableVertexAttribArray(0)
glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, cube_vertex_buffer)
glVertexAttribPointer(
    0,  # attribute 0. No particular reason for 0, but must match the layout in the shader.
    3,  # len(vertex_data)
    GL_FLOAT,  # type
    GL_FALSE,  # ormalized?
    0,  # stride
    null  # array buffer offset (c_type == void*)
)

# 2nd attribute buffer : colors
glEnableVertexAttribArray(1)
glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, cube_color_buffer)
glVertexAttribPointer(
    1,  # attribute 0. No particular reason for 0, but must match the layout in the shader.
    3,  # len(vertex_data)
    GL_FLOAT,  # type
    GL_FALSE,  # normalized?
    0,  # stride
    null  # array buffer offset (c_type == void*)
)

# Draw the triangles !
glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLES, 0, 12 * 3)  # 3 indices starting at 0 -> 1 triangle

# Not strictly necessary because we only have
glDisableVertexAttribArray(0)
glDisableVertexAttribArray(1)

# ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
# Draw Background

array_type = GLfloat * len(background_vertex_data)
glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, background_vertex_buffer)
glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, len(background_vertex_data) * 4, array_type(*background_vertex_data), GL_STATIC_DRAW)

array_type = GLfloat * len(background_color_data)
glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, background_color_buffer)
glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, len(background_color_data) * 4, array_type(*background_color_data), GL_STATIC_DRAW)

ViewMatrix = np.identity(4)
ModelMatrix = np.identity(4)
mvp = ProjectionMatrix * ViewMatrix * ModelMatrix

glUniformMatrix4fv(background_matrix_id, 1, GL_FALSE, mvp.data)

# Turning a Videostream in a Texture --------------------------
# convert image to OpenGL texture format
tx_image = cv2.flip(left_frame, 0)
tx_image = Image.fromarray(tx_image)
ix = tx_image.size[0]
iy = tx_image.size[1]
tx_image = tx_image.tobytes('raw', 'RGBX', 0, -1)  # BGRX
# tx_image = np.asarray(tx_image)

# create texture
texture_id = glGenTextures(1)
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, texture_id)
# glPixelStorei(GL_UNPACK_ALIGNMENT, 1)
# Filtering and mipmapping of the model
glTexParameterf(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GL_CLAMP)
glTexParameterf(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GL_CLAMP)
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_LINEAR)
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_LINEAR)
# glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGBA, ix, iy, 0, GL_RGBA, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, tx_image)
# glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGB, ix, iy, 0, GL_RGB, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, tx_image)
glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGB, ix, iy, 0, GL_RGB, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, tx_image)

# Generate mipmaps
glGenerateMipmap(GL_TEXTURE_2D)
# glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, 3, ix, iy, 0, GL_BGRA, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, tx_image)

# ----------------------------------------------------------

# 1rst attribute buffer : vertices
glEnableVertexAttribArray(0)
glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, background_vertex_buffer)
glVertexAttribPointer(
    0,  # attribute 0. No particular reason for 0, but must match the layout in the shader.
    3,  # len(vertex_data)
    GL_FLOAT,  # type
    GL_FALSE,  # ormalized?
    0,  # stride
    null  # array buffer offset (c_type == void*)
)

# 2nd attribute buffer : colors
glEnableVertexAttribArray(1)
glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, background_color_buffer)
glVertexAttribPointer(
    1,  # attribute 0. No particular reason for 0, but must match the layout in the shader.
    2,  # len(vertex_data)
    GL_FLOAT,  # type
    GL_FALSE,  # normalized?
    0,  # stride
    null  # array buffer offset (c_type == void*)
)

# Draw the triangle !
glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLES, 0, 12 * 3)  # 3 indices starting at 0 -> 1 triangle

# Not strictly necessary because we only have
glDisableVertexAttribArray(0)
glDisableVertexAttribArray(1)

# Swap front and back buffers
glfw.swap_buffers(window)

# Poll for and process events
glfw.poll_events()
```

I'm still a big rookie and I'd appreciate any kind of advice on
structuring the code too.

Comment: Welcome to SO. What's your exact problem? What do you expect and what do you get instead?

Comment: I'm getting a coloured cube and a coloured quad (background) behind the cube, but I want a coloured cube and a textured quad (background) behind the cube. The texture should be a frame from my camera, so that I can see the camera video in the background.
But I'm not getting that, I'm missing something

Comment: "*not getting that*" explains nothing. Start by drawing a simple quad, then with a simple texture. Then, the cube and with texture. Later, add the image coming from the camera.

Comment: So how do your shaders look like?

Comment: @Ripi2 I'm sorry that I wasn't specific enough: It seems like the code where I'm turning the frame into a texture is not working and I thought that I'm missing something, where you could probably tell me what it could be
But after trying what you told me (drawing a quad and simply putting a texture on it) and after looking at the shaders, I found one of the problems: the shader is just assigning colours and not the colours of the texture
But how do I tell the fragment shader to put a texture on the quad and put colours on the cube?

Comment: @derhass thanks for your question: I noticed one of the problems, that I'm just assigning colours in the fragment shader and not colours of the texture
but how do I combine giving the cube colour and assigning a texture to the quad in one fragment shader?

Comment: @user3019423: well, the very same tutorial which you referenced in your question actually covers this.